# QLongLong weird compare

Tags: c++, qt

I need to compare some free space on my hard drive using two [QLonglong](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qlonglong-typedef) and I face this behavior using this code:

```
if(deviceSize < size);
{
    qDebug() << "The device" << device << "has only" << deviceSize << "bytes left";
    qDebug() << (deviceSize < size) << deviceSize << size;
}
```

which outputs:

```
The device "disk1s2" has only 217528172544 bytes left 
false 217528172544 998054018
```

As the condition `(deviceSize < size)` returns false I don't even understand how it can go into the `if()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
if(deviceSize < size);
//                   ^
```

That means that it does not matter what condition you have, the block will always be executed since you have an empty statement for the condition.

Comment: erf. I'm so dumb :( Thank you once again Laszlo !

Comment: @ꜱᴀᴍᴏᴛʜ: :) no worries.